# Xamarin Forms Visual Studio doesnt deploy

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, enterprise

When I run with emulator my project doesn't show any error. Only this happens:
[image]

About 3-4 minutes after it shows Ready instead of Deploy Started but doesn't show anything on Emulator.

About 3-4 minutes after:
[image]

This case doesn't change. About 15-20 minutes later I cancel deploy. When I run project with my android device it works well. what is a problem? who Could help me?

Comment: Added the images inline (clickable to full size)

Comment: Can you try to unlock your emulator?

Comment: I downloaded sdk api 23 problem has solved. now it works well